# Ag-grid Column sort comparator does not work in Pivot mode with column grouping

Tags: reactjs, sorting, ag-grid, ag-grid-react, group

I have a data table in ag-grid and am displaying it in both normal mode and pivot mode. I'm using a custom comparator function to sort one of the columns, which contains strings.

This comparator works in the normal mode, but in pivot mode with that column selected, the sort is done alphabetically, not based on the custom comparator defined on the column.

The set-up is similar to the one defined here, under custom group sorting: https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grouping-sorting/

I tried troubleshooting by grouping the columns by default, but the comparator function did not get triggered in group mode.

The AgGrid version specified in package.json is 25.2.0 (both `@ag-grid-community/react` & `@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules` dependencies)

Here is a snippet of the code for reference:

Imports:

```
import { AgGridReact } from '@ag-grid-community/react';
import {
  AllModules,
  ColDef,
  Column,
  ColumnApi,
  FilterChangedEvent,
  FirstDataRenderedEvent,
  GridApi,
  GridReadyEvent,
  ColumnVisibleEvent,
  ColumnValueChangedEvent
} from '@ag-grid-enterprise/all-modules';
```

Column defs:

```
  const defaultColDef = useMemo<ColDef>(() => {
    return {
      flex: 1,
      sortable: true,
      resizable: true,
      filter: true,
      enableRowGroup: true,
      enablePivot: true,
      cellClass: 'stringType',
    };
  }, []);

  const autoGroupColumnDef = useMemo<ColDef>(() => {
    return {
      minWidth: 250,
    };
  }, []);


  const[columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState<ColDef[]>([
    {
      headerName: "Year",
      field: 'year',
      cellClass: 'numberType',
    },
    {
      headerName: "Fruit",
      field: 'fruit',
      filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
      rowGroup: true,
      comparator: (a, b) => {
        const fruitListSortOrder = [
          'Banana',
          'Orange',
          'Apple',
          'Lemon',
          'Watermelon',
          'Papaya',
        ];
        return fruitListSortOrder.indexOf(a) - fruitListSortOrder.indexOf(b);
      },
    },
    {
      headerName: "Value",
      field: "value",
      enableValue: true,
      enableRowGroup: false,
      enablePivot: false,
      aggFunc: "sum",
      filter: "agNumberColumnFilter",
    },
  ]);
```

AgGrid React component:

```
<AgGridReact
  modules={AllModules}
  defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
  columnDefs={columnDefs}
  autoGroupColumnDef={autoGroupColumnDef}
  sideBar
  onGridReady={onGridReady}
  rowData={rowData}
/>
```

I added a console.log statement to the comparator function. In normal mode the function is triggered on sort, but in group mode the function is not run.

Comment: did you find a solution? i am facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `pivotComparator` instead/with `comparator` in your column definition. **Also, take care that the inputs `a` and `b` are given in `strings` even if they are numbers.**

**Order of Pivot Value Column Groups**
Pivot value columns are the column groups created by the pivot values - eg if 'Country' is a pivot column, then the Pivot Value Column Groups are 'Ireland', 'UK', etc. These columns are ordered alphabetically by default. To override this, provide pivotComparator(a,b) function in the column definition.

Reference: [pivotComparator](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/pivoting/#reference-pivoting-pivotComparator)

```
{
      headerName: "Fruit",
      field: 'fruit',
      filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
      rowGroup: true,
      pivotComparator: (a: string, b: string) => {
        const fruitListSortOrder = [
          'Banana',
          'Orange',
          'Apple',
          'Lemon',
          'Watermelon',
          'Papaya',
        ];
        return fruitListSortOrder.indexOf(a) - fruitListSortOrder.indexOf(b);
      },
    },
```